# Open webbrowser with specific url in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

How would i go about opening the webbrowser with a specific url on button click.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the following code in the button Click event handler:

```
var task = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.WebBrowserTask
            {
        URL = uri
            };

            task.Show();
```

Comment: Can I put a string variable where the URL is?

Comment: Note that the `URL` property is now deprecated in favor of `Uri`

Answer (score 1):

with this code on button handler event you can navigate to the url assigned to var URL

```
        WebBrowserTask wbTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        var URL = "http://create.msdn.com";
        wbTask.Uri = new Uri(URL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        wbTask.Show();
```

Comment: You could improve this answer with a bit of context describing why this works and links to the documentation of WebBrowserTask. It doesn't seem to mention how this code is executed after a button click with details of the event and registration.