# Possible to show the URL-Bar in a Webbrowser control on Windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am currently playing a little bit around with the development environment. At the moment I am writing a small app, which adresses a Webbrowser-Control.

Therefore I was looking for an opportunity, to show the URL-bar and maybe manipulating the URL via input of the user. Is this anyway possible, or not implemented for the webbrowser control?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebBrowser control itself doesn't have a URL bar. It is simply a control that has the ability to display HTML and run Javascript. The easiest way way to simulate one would be to create a textbox. You can then use its `Navigate` method to load the webpage:

```
myWebBrowserControl.Navigate(myTextboxUrl.Text);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), but your app loses all control of the user's activities within this task.

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be easier to just launch the web browser task directly.  Customizing the URL bar would probably require rolling your own.

Here's a related question about opening the browser: [Open webbrowser with specific url in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585513/open-webbrowser-with-specific-url-in-wp7)